# How <af:goLink> is working?

Tags: java, jsf, jdeveloper, breadcrumbs

I am currently trying to open one .jsff from another .jsff. Some kind of bread crumbs.

```
<af:group id="g1">
  <af:goLink text="#{dictionary['page.Processing']}" destination="/jsff/view.jsff" id="ot2" inlineStyle="margin:10pt; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; font-family:Tahoma;"/>
  <af:outputText value=" > " id="ot4"/>
  <af:goLink text="#{dictionary['label.module.WorkingWithStatforms']}" destination="/jsff/processform.jsff" id="gl1" inlineStyle="margin:10pt; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; font-family:Tahoma;"/>
</af:group>
```

[image]

But it is not working. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use goLink to do JSF navigation - instead use an af:link and set the action property.